# How can I integrate a WebRTC video call with picture-in-picture mode in Flutter for both Android and iOS platforms?

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc, flutter-dependencies, flutter-webrtc

I have been working on integrating WebRTC video call with picture-in-picture mode in a Flutter app that runs on both Android and iOS platforms. I have tried several plugins, but unfortunately, none of them seem to work with WebRTC video streaming. So far, I have tried the "[simple_pip_mode](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_pip_mode)" and "[pip_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/pip_flutter)" plugins. While the "pip_flutter" plugin supports video players, I am unsure of how to integrate it with WebRTC video streaming. Could anyone suggest a plugin or a solution to achieve this integration successfully? Thank you.

As mentioned in my question, I have tried using the "simple_pip_mode" and "pip_flutter" plugins to integrate WebRTC video call with picture-in-picture mode in a Flutter app that runs on both Android and iOS platforms. However, none of these plugins seem to work with WebRTC video streaming. I was hoping to find a plugin or a solution that could successfully integrate WebRTC video call with picture-in-picture mode.

Comment: Have you finds any solution?